# Weight paint (for particles) not working

Tags: particles, weight-painting, hair, vertex-groups

my first post here.
I'm using beta of Blender 2.8 and am a beginner here.
So my problem is during [Blender Guru's beginner tutorial on particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_niVFliJ0E), he is able to use the weight paint easily, but when I tried clicking, it still remained blue.

Is it something Blender 2.8 does differently than on his videos? Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `0 weight` brush with *add setting*. Nothing will change for `+ 0` operation

[image]

Change your weight and try it again. There are many options(not that much compare with Photoshop) in the Tool panel, you should check it out.